# How to set position of gameobject for animation in script

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have two game object.
Both gameobject positions are different...
I attached same animation clip to both gameobject.

In one game object I am don't want any change in animation clip.
I just want to use same animation clip on different gameobject but animation timing is different
&  In other Gameobject I am just want to play animation at 0.30 s but I not knowing how set position of this gameobject in script.

I am assign below script to second game object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ani3 : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {

        animation ["@cube"].time = 0.30f;
        //how to set position of gameobjet

    }
void Update () {
gameObject.animation.Play("@cube");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a **empty game object** and nest one of the game object as child and change the position of the empty game object ,it is work for me.